# Bumblebee using nouveau instead of proprietary

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Running glmark2 with optirun on Nvidia 740M on 15.04:

```
OpenGL Information
GL_VENDOR:     nouveau
GL_RENDERER:   Gallium 0.4 on NV108
GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
```

I want to use proprietary driver.

bumblebee.conf: http://pastebin.com/yXVymPh0

Driver configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFQJJ.jpg

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I'm really dumb. I had duplicate Driver= in first block. Sorry